# Nativescript Button Overlay

Tags: ios, css, xml, nativescript

[image]I was wondering how to overlay a button on top of a picture in Nativescript?

I have tried using background-image but the button does not end up on top of the picture.

Currently what I have is:

```
<Image src="~/images/image.jpg" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" />
        <Button text ="image" tap="tapAction" class="ButtonOne"/>

<Image src="~/images/image2.jpg" stretch="aspectFit" class="image2" horizontalAlignment="right"/>
        <Button text ="image2" tap="tapAction1" class="ButtonTwo"/>
```

I used stacklayout here so I could easily overlay these pictures and buttons on the same page. Now what I want to achieve is to remove the border and place the button text on top of the image somewhere.

I have been experimenting with some of the CSS properties such as background-image but I cannot seem to achieve a good answer for this.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the correct direction for this problem. I want to find a way to overlay a button on top of the image.

Thank you!

Here is what I have currently and I trying to eliminate the white space and place the respective button on the bottom of each and every picture. So 4 pics in total and 4 buttons on the bottom for each!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `GridLayout` like this:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto" backgroundImage="~/images/yourpic.png">
 <Button text="Hello Guy!" row="0" col="0" />
</GridLayout>
```

However, it is easier (less markup) with a *StackLayout* taking the same approach of backgroundImage on the Stack.

Comment: But how would I incorporate multiple pictures this way, since I am trying to have multiple pictures having their own respective buttons.

Comment: Use multiple Stacks or Grids within another layout. So have a parent Stack (or grid) then duplicate the above sample to repeat the layout.

Comment: I am currently using stacklayouts inside a bigger gridlayout. I am thinking of doing it in either two methods: 

The first method involving the backgroundImage property, but I cannot seem to be able to place one image underneath the other in a stack like formation. I am using: 

<GridLayout rows="*,*,*" columns="*,*,*" >

 <StackLayout backgroundImage="~/images/Gleason.jpg" class="Gleason" stretch="aspectFit">

     <Button text ="Gleason" tap="tapAction" class="ButtonOne" />

    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>

And a similiar structure for the next 3 pictures and buttons.

Comment: But because of this method background images are overlapping and I cannot seem to be able to control their dimensions. How would I go about placing these images and buttons? Would it just be a different layout altogether or would there be some way of fitting these images and buttons on the page? Thanks!

Comment: if you have a screenshot of what you have and what you are trying to achieve that would help to figure out what you want.

Comment: Check this code out for a snack on I did: http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/05/30/horizontal-scroller.html I have a button on top of an image, this should give you an idea of how to put a button on top of an image.

Comment: Yeah that is extremely useful but my main problem is how I would go about eliminating the white space between pictures?

Comment: By adjusting the layout :) you might need to check the padding/margins and just the general layout between the items. If you have white space then you can remove it, but that would require more of your project to see what's going on to be honest.

Comment: Sorry one last question i promise, I dont understand where you instantiated your pictures was it in the gridlayout itself or somewhere external? Thank you so much for your help and I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: In that snippet I didn't add it just to keep the markup simple, but inside each of the individual `grid-layouts` just put an image and set its `row` and `col` properties. Also be aware of `colSpan` and `rowSpan`, those are great for stretching a view across multiple rows/columns.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an `AbsoluteLayout`, for example:

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="100%" height="100%">
  <Image src="~/images/image.jpg" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" top="0" left="0" />
  <Button text="image" tap="tapAction" class="ButtonOne" top="20" left="20"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: In this case, the aspect fit stretch doesnt seem to work and I just end up having a blown up picture that takes the entire screen. Would I need to use CSS or is there something in XML to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: how do you make the image overlap the button and stay over the button? Images that overlap with buttons are always under the them. EDIT: add higher androidElevation (for android)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to Add multiple rows and columns with images and buttons in a gridLayout. In this example you have 2 equal height images below each other:

```
<GridLayout rows="1*,1*" columns="auto">
    <Image row="0" src="~/images/image.jpg" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" />
    <Button row="0" text ="image" tap="tapAction" class="ButtonOne"/>

    <Image row="1" src="~/images/image2.jpg" stretch="aspectFit" class="image2" horizontalAlignment="right"/>
    <Button row="1" text ="image2" tap="tapAction1" class="ButtonTwo"/>
</GridLayout>
```

The advantage of this gridLayout is that the image and button are always on the same position and it is expendable.